# jQuery not working in html and I don't know what i'm doing wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't know why nothing is happening when I mouse over the div. I may have an issue with how I linked the javascript files, but I looked this up and from what I found, am doing that correctly. On top of that, I couldn't find any other help for my problem.

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
    Title
</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="menu">Hi</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body
{
    background-color: #CCFFFF;
}
.menu
{
    background-color: #666666;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 70px;
    height: 30px;
    font-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div:nth-child(1)').mouseover(function(){
        $('div:nth-child(1)').slideDown('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: what's the console output mate? If you think you have mislinked the jQuery file, try <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> in place of your <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: What are you expecting it to do, and what is it doing differently from that?

Comment: @AkiraDawson I tried that and it didn't work. I'm still not sure why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accepted answer will not work if you are trying to achieve an invisible div that can stil be moused over. `slideDown`, only works on a div with `display: none` not `visibility:hidden` but if you set your div to `display:none` then you can't mouse over it. One way to have an invisible div that you can still mouse over is to wrap it in another div like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="contain">
        <div class="menu">Hi</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Then you execute this function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#contain').on({
        mouseenter: function(){
            $('.menu').slideDown('slow');
        }, mouseleave: function() {
            $('.menu').slideUp('slow');        
        }
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brewersomething/GnLhx/)

Answer (score 2):

`slideDown` works on elements that are hidden, and then exposes them. You have a `div` that is showing, and on mouseover expect it to slide down? (No sense!) - Apply the slidedown effect to an element that is hidden and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Oh,you misunderstood function slideDown(),it displays the matched (hidden) elements with a sliding motion.The div is visible,you should hide it first,then you can use slideDown() to display it.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
    Title
</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('div:nth-child(1)').mouseover(function(){
            $('div:nth-child(1)').slideUp('slow');
        });

        $('button').click(function(){
            $('div:nth-child(1)').slideDown('slow');
        });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="menu">Hi</div>
    <button>show</button>
</body>
</html>
```